# I need column wise median of list_of_dicts_of_lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, median

I have this data:

```
list_of_dicts_of_lists = [
    {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4], 'c': [3,2], 'd': [2,5]}
    {'a': [2,2], 'b': [2,2], 'c': [1,6], 'd': [4,7]}
    {'a': [2,2], 'b': [5,2], 'c': [3,2], 'd': [2,2]}
    {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4], 'c': [1,6], 'd': [5,5]} 
    ]
```

I need this result:

```
median_dict_of_lists = (
    {'a': [1.5,2], 'b': [3,3], 'c': [2,4], 'd': [3,5]}
    )
```

...where each value is the median of the respective column above.

I need the mode dictionary where available and median dictionary when no mode exists. I was able to do quick and dirty `statistics.mode()` by stringing each dict, getting mode of list of strings, then `ast.literal_eval(most_common_string)` back to a dict, but I need a column wise median in cases where there is no mode.

I know how to use `statistics.median()`; however, the nested notation to apply it to this case, column wise, is frazzling me.

The data is all floats; I wrote it as int just to make easier to read.

Comment: thanks for two quick answers, very hocus pocus both.  I'll run some tests and pick a favorite, until both upvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following  dictionary comprehension with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
median_dict_of_lists = {i : list(np.median([x[i] for x in list_of_dicts_of_lists], axis=0)) 
                    for i in 'abcd'}
```

Which returns the same:

```
{'a': [1.5, 2.0], 'c': [2.0, 4.0], 'b': [3.0, 3.0], 'd': [3.0, 5.0]}
```

To explain, `np.median([x[i] for x in list_of_dicts_of_lists], axis=0)`, embedded in the dictionary comprehension, is going through each key `i` in `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, and getting the median of each key for all of your dicts in your original list of dicts. This median is getting assigned to a new dictionary with the appropriate key via the dictionary comprehension syntax.

There is a good explanation of the dictionary comprehension syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it), and the [documentation for np.median](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) explains the function itself quite well

Comment: Less cryptic than the other solution IMO, and obviously more concise. Note that the `list` conversions aren't necessary...

Comment: True, at least for the `list('abcd')` (editted). You could also get rid of the `list` conversion of the `np.array` which is outputted by `np.median`, but I was trying to get the output exactly as shown by the OP, in which it looks like a list and not an `np.array`. In the end, though, it wouldn't make a difference...

Comment: And the explicit  `np.array` conversion is unnecessary too. Maybe a quick explanation of how that works will please the OP :)

Comment: True! Don't know why I was doing that!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `statistics.median` with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import statistics
import itertools
list_of_dicts_of_lists = [
  {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4], 'c': [3,2], 'd': [2,5]},
  {'a': [2,2], 'b': [2,2], 'c': [1,6], 'd': [4,7]},
  {'a': [2,2], 'b': [5,2], 'c': [3,2], 'd': [2,2]},
  {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4], 'c': [1,6], 'd': [5,5]} 
]
new_listing = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(itertools.chain(*map(lambda x:x.items(), list_of_dicts_of_lists)), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
d = {a:zip(*map(lambda x:x[-1], b)) for a, b in new_listing}
last_data = ({a:[statistics.median(b), statistics.median(c)] for a, [b, c] in d.items()},)
```

Output:

```
({'a': [1.5, 2.0], 'b': [3.0, 3.0], 'c': [2.0, 4.0], 'd': [3.0, 5.0]},)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also break it down in small steps with meaningful names to make the solution more maintainable.   For example:

```
# combine dictionary arrays into a 3d matrix, removing dictionary keys
valueMatrix3D = [ list(row.values()) for row in list_of_dicts_of_lists ]

# compute the median for each row's array (axis 1)
medianArrays  = np.median(valueMatrix3D,axis=1)

# reassemble into a dictionary with original keys
medianDict = { key:list(array) for key,array in zip(list_of_dicts_of_lists[0] ,medianArrays) }
```